# Simple Error while aplying mySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm making a small trigger that inserts an entry to a log_table if a field is changed during an update.

My code is this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER Set_Aloc_Spent_Before_Update BEFORE UPDATE ON Tbl_Eventos

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


    SET @ALC_BF = (Select AlocSpent from `Tbl_Projects` where project_id = NEW.projectId);
    SET @ALC_AFTER = (Select calculate_aloc_spent(NEW.projectId));

    IF @ALC_BF != @ALC_AFTER THEN

        UPDATE Tbl_Projects SET AlocSpent = (Select calculate_aloc_spent(NEW.projectId)) WHERE Project_ID = NEW.projectId;

    END IF;
END
```

Sorry but I don't know much of mysql and I need this trigger to work.

When I try to add the script to the DB I get: "Error while aplying mySQL Script"

```
Executing:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `team_mgmt`.`Set_Aloc_Spent_Before_Update`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `team_mgmt`$$
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`%` TRIGGER `team_mgmt`.`Set_Aloc_Spent_Before_Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `Tbl_Eventos` FOR EACH ROW FOLLOWS `Calculate_Duration_update`
$$
DELIMITER ;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
SQL Statement:
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`%` TRIGGER `team_mgmt`.`Set_Aloc_Spent_Before_Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `Tbl_Eventos` FOR EACH ROW FOLLOWS `Calculate_Duration_update`
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Flimzy it's there now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I eddited the code for a simpler version but I still get the same error.